# Laravel skip constraint violation upon first time creating model

Tags: mysql, laravel, constraints, laravel-5

I want to know if it is possible to skip or ignore the constraint violation upon creating a user. I have a user model with a foreign key `address_id`.

```
Schema::table('user', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('address_id')->references('address_id')->on('address')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Upon creating a user i want to create a user without a address yet which will be added later on.

```
return User::create([
    'first_name' => $data['firstname'],
    'last_name' => $data['lastname'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);
```

but hence the constraint violation. It is possible to do this?

EDIT:

Thus i would like to keep the constraints but the example above runs into a constraint violation so what is the best way to work around this? Making a dummy address entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the DB for the time you are adding the model:

```
protected function turnOffDatabaseChecks()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
    Eloquent::unguard();
}

protected function turnOnDatabaseChecks()
{
    DB::statement("SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';");
    Eloquent::reguard();
}
```

Then in your user model:

```
$this->turnOffDatabaseChecks();

$user = User::create([
    'first_name' => $data['firstname'],
    'last_name' => $data['lastname'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);

$this->turnOnDatabaseChecks();

return $user;
```

However, I'd be very cautious in using this and would ask yourself why you have a foreign key constraint that you wish to ignore.

Comment: Thanks, i prefer not to ignore, like you said, but i dont know how to work around it. It is a registration form with just these fields: firstname, lastname, email and password. I would like the keep the constrains but dont know how in this example, worst case would be skipping it like youre example..

Comment: if a user does not have to have an address then why is it a constraint?

Comment: @chaseenyc, i am a bit new to this, you are probably right i thought it would be a good practise to make keep the database tight. So this is just not possible because constraints are made for this.